# How to add headers from different rmd files into one TOC

Tags: html, yaml, r-markdown, knitr, tableofcontents

I have three different rmd files which I will knitr to html output (three pages in the same website). I want each page to share the same TOC (which hence also includes headers from other rmd files) I can't put everything under the same rmd file because it takes too long to load in the browser. I needed hence to split it into 3 pages.

```
# site.yml

name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "Home"
  left:
    - text: "Page 1"
      href: parte1.html
    - text: "Page 2"
      href: parte2.html

# index.rmd 

---
title: " my file "
author: " me "
date: "26/02/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float:
      collapsed: yes
      smooth_scroll: yes
  word_document: default
---

# (same YAML for the two other rmd files: "Page 1" and "Page 2")
```